# Custom Directive for number only input not working for HTML inside controller bound div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was searching for custom directive for number only input for AngularJS JavaScript and I got hands on a working directive but it isn't working when I am using it for input box which is inside body or div bound to a controller.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="xyz">
  <p>Demo of AngularJS Numbers Only Directive</p>
  <p>Input below will accept only numbers.</p>
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="val" numbers-only  /></p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }            
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

JSFiddle: [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kgp0z2y9/1/)

It Works properly if I delete the controller part from the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an undefined controller, removing it will fix it:

http://jsfiddle.net/kgp0z2y9/3/

Or create it

```
app.controller('xyz', function(){});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgp0z2y9/5/

Comment: It is really awkward, I am done exactly same thing my actual code but there it isn't working.

Comment: Have you included the script on the page where the controller is contained?

Comment: Yes, Lewis. The controller is loaded properly, I am printing a message on the console but still... the problem is there.

Comment: jquery or some other script like bootrstrap.js can cause problem to this
?

Comment: JQuery and Bootstrap probably won't be the problem.. Without seeing your code it would be difficult as the jsfiddle works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121610/discussion-between-lewis-and-deathnote).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because your controller isn't defined, thus throwing an error, breaking the angular directive too.

Just define the controller in your JS:

```
app.controller('xyz', function() {return {};})
```

and it should work ([Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgp0z2y9/2/))

Comment: It is really awkward, I am done exactly same thing my actual code but there it isn't working.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?
Can you create a new JSFiddle reproducing the same error? It's possible that there is a typo in how your controller is defined which is causing another problem, so please update your question with the code exactly as you have it.

Comment: It is working properly in the fiddle Caffeinated.tech, I have pasted pastebin links for the real code where it isn't working and there are no errors on the console.